# FormData Vuejs input type file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ребята как можно с помощью FormData отправить одним запросом несколько input type file причем с разными name

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="file1" multiple>
<input type="file2" name="file2" multiple>
<input type="file3" name="file3" multiple>
<input type="file4" name="file4" multiple>
<form>
```

Comment: [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру так:

```js
var form = new FormData();

$('.files').change(function(){
    var files = this.files; //это массив файлов    
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        form.append("file[]",files[i]); 
    }    
})

$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/your/url',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data : form,
      success: function(result){
          console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(err){
          console.log(err);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" class="files">
<input type="file" class="files">
<input type="file" class="files">


<button>click</button>
```

- [об Append](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)
- [о файлах в целом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: Вопрос про vue.js-реализацию, ответ с jquery — бинго :-)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko я не помню, чтоб отвечал на такой вопрос) Ибо я никогда не пишу ответ на jquery если метки на вопросе соответствующей нет, а тем более если vue. Может где что сбойнуло?)